# Export all models in .blend file as separate .glb files

Tags: export, gltf

I have a single .blend file containing multiple models, I would like to GLB export all of them to individual files (named <model_name>.glb) with a single action, just as if I had done

`File -> Export -> glTF 2.0 (.glb/gltf) -> Include -> Selected Models`

when selecting a model going through all models in the .blend file.

Is there a convenient way of achieving this, or do I need to write a python script to do it?